# Is there an easy way to make anything draggable in Silverlight XAML?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, controls, drag-and-drop, draggable

My target is an entire listbox clipped in a canvas, but I guess there should be something that can work for all controls?

How to make a control draggable and even attached x or y constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to cycle thru all the child controls and add handlers to mouse events.

Within those events you control the drag and the bounds.